# How to find Guide in Romania for Jewish Ancestry Search?

Tags: jewish, romania

Planning on going to Romania in June, 2015.  Need a guide/translator/driver to take me to Ramnicu Sarat to try to find any information on my family.

How do I go about finding someone?

Comment: Welcome to G&FH SE!  While you are waiting for an answer you may like to review [previous Q&As here on Romanian ancestry](http://genealogy.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/romania).

Answer (score 2):

There's a guide to Romanian Jewish genealogy on the Israel Genealogy Research Association (IGRA) site:

http://genealogy.org.il/resources/resource-guide-romania/

The author also gives his e-mail address, so if you have further questions you can contact him.

Answer (score 1):

You could try asking on JewishGen's Romania-SIG (Special Interest Group) e-mail mailing list which is free.

http://www.jewishgen.org/ListManager

Answer (score 1):

You can try [Fernando Klabin](http://ewigerjude.blogspot.co.il/). He is a romanian certified tour guide.
I have been in touch with him in the past to check if he had info on my Romanian ancestry (Secureni, todays Southern Ukraine, in the border with Moldova).